# Remote SSH keys (ECDSA key) issue when accessing from client-side

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, remote, armbian

I have a Rockpro64 single board computer that I am trying to access remotely via an eMMC flashed Ubuntu iso image from here: https://www.armbian.com/rockpro64/, but keep getting the error message below. I was able to access the IP remotely from various laptops fine before by SSHing from the terminal, but after I failed at installing the program I wanted to install properly, I re-flashed the eMMC and have been getting this error ever since when accessing from other laptops (client-side) - I can SSH from the server-side fine with no issue FWIW.

```
    @    WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!     @
    @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
    IT IS POSSIBLE THAT SOMEONE IS DOING SOMETHING NASTY!
    Someone could be eavesdropping on you right now (man-in-the-middle attack)!
    It is also possible that a host key has just been changed.
    The fingerprint for the ECDSA key sent by the remote host is
    SHA256:IWefc//FoZcRXp...fpsF0eM.
    Please contact your system administrator.

Add correct host key in C:\\Users\\User/.ssh/known_hosts to get rid of this message.
Offending ECDSA key in C:\\Users\\User/.ssh/known_hosts:3
ECDSA host key for <remote IP address> has changed and you have requested strict checking.
Host key verification failed.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is telling you that you are connecting to a different machine, which is true. The old machine disappeared when you reflashed it.

You should edit the  text file (on your windows machine) c:/Users/User/.ssh/known_hosts and delete the third line (the ":3" in the error message tells you the line you need to remove).

The first time you connect after removing the line it will tell you you are connecting to a new machine.

Comment: You have files called C:\Users\User/.ssh/known_hosts on your Ubuntu machine???? You need to make this change on the "laptops", not the Rockpro64 machine.

Comment: Ohh I see now the exact path it's specifying and that means it's on one of the windows machines I was using, thanks!

How do I edit that on Windows 10 though? I'm only used to "sudo nano known_hosts" haha

Comment: Sorry I removed my original response because I wasn't given the edit option, but I just was not understanding what you said, but now I do!

Comment: Editing files on a windows machine depends on what you have installed. I would **suggest** the following. Press the "windows" key (lower left, typically 2 keys to the left of the spacebar), press and release the "r" key, then release the windows key. This should bring up a dialog box. type "cmd" and press enter in this and it should bring up a terminal.  type "cd \Users\User\.ssh" and then "wordpad known_hosts" to bring up a graphical word processor. delete the line using lots of backspaces, use the "File" menu to save and then quit. Try the ssh again.

Comment: Okay ty for this, but when I was in /Users/User.ssh and typed "wordpad known_hosts" I got an error, but notepad worked instead and deleting the third line solved my problem thanks so much!! :)

Comment: I spoke a little too soon, after typing the password for the hosts IP I get:
Permission denied (publickey).

Comment: I reflashed the eMMC with the OS and I had to do all this over again, but I didn't get the last error this time.